# CSS: two div/a-block, buttons not working the same despite exact code

Tags: html, css

(After reading, let me know if you have a better question title)

Ok, so this is (at least, to me) a phenomenon.  As I learn, I run into things that baffle me because I haven't yet learned some simple concept... but with this, I felt it's worth asking here.

What I want to do is create two, vertically stacked, rectangle, buttons.  Both of these buttons will work exactly the same, except they each have different links and text.  So, basically the same css!  There are four more requirements:

1 - They must be in a parent div.

2 - They must have two states, normal and hover, with an opacity change.

3 - They need to be on top of each other (close to each other).

4 - The text in the divs cannot be in the a's.  This is for my own styling (not shown in any of this code)

Now, the problem that seems to arise when I do this, is that the second button (the one on the bottom), spazes out! As a cursor goes over the top part of it, it will constantly refresh (I think)!
Here is the code (note:classes "begin" and "late" are identical):

CSS:

```
    div.buts {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
}
div.begin {
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#123;
    opacity:.9;
    color:#EEE;
}
div.begin:hover {
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#123;
    opacity:1;
    color:#EEE;
}
div.late {
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#123;
    opacity:.9;
    color:#EEE;
}
div.late:hover {
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#123;
    opacity:1;
    color:#EEE;
}
a.block {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="buts">
    <div class="begin">BEGIN<a class="block" href="https://www.google.com/"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="late">LATE  <a class="block" href="https://www.google.com/"></a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Here is the jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9p26/

See? When you mouse over the "LATE" button, at the top where the text is, but also to the right where it's not, you get the spaz-y thing.

I tried a few different things.  I made multiple buttons: this creates more buttons with the same issue as the second button (the first one is the only one that works properly).  I added a margin to the second button to see if it was just some overlapping thing, this gave me two results.  If the margin is small(1-10px), the problem occurs, if it's larger(20px+) then there is no spazzing (but the button are then no longer close, so nogo).  So this indicates it's related to the text in the div?  Finally, I tried turning off opacity. If the bottom div's (class="late") opacity is turned off (setting both normal and hover to 1), nothing happens: the spazzing still occurs but the button no longer changes opacity.  BUT if I change the top div's (class="begin") opacity to 1 for both hover and normal, it's fixed... but I assume this just means the second button because the first, and the first always works.  I don't get it.

Can anybody figure this out?  Is this is stupid question?  Will somebody with far superior CSS knowledge explain a very simple concept I seemed to miss, and solve my problem?

Comment: So confused, this massive wall of text. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/m9p26/3/) Put the text in `<a>`.

Comment: Sorry!  I should have said, it can't be in the <a> because it need to be styled in the div, and not the link.

Comment: Wrap the text in a `<span>` and set `position: absolute;` [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/m9p26/6/)

Comment: You can set `position:relative` to all divs then use     `position:absolute; left:0; top:0;` on a.block. But this is not best practice.

Comment: **" The text in the divs cannot be in the a's. This is for my own styling (not shown in any of this code)"** This is just bad practice and there is no good reason for it.

Comment: Everybody gave different workable solutions!  Thanks!  This helped a lot.  Apologies for over-explanation.

Comment: remove `display:block` from `a.block`.. and you are done... :)

Comment: @NishantSolanki yes, but then it fails to become a "button" and is just a text link.

Comment: yeah... why dont you put `BEGIN` in your `<a>` tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically the issue here is that the text isn't in the "a" tag so your "a" tag is getting pushed down. Since you have the height of that "a" tag set at 100% it moves it right over the second button causing weird behavior towards the top of the buttons. There are two simple solutions.

- Put the link text into the "a" tag where it belongs and then style accordingly. That solution is here (http://jsfiddle.net/m9p26/8/). You end up with the following code snippets. First the html:

  ```
  <div class="begin">
      <a class="block" href="https://www.google.com/">BEGIN</a>
  </div>
  ```

  And the css:

  ```
  // example for styling the "a" tag
  a.block {
      display:block;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      text-decoration:none;
      color: black;
  }
  ```

  This works really well. Given the power of css you can really style your "a" to look however you want.
- Assuming this is not acceptable you can set the "a" tag to be `position: relative` and you should be able to move it up to the appropriate position from there (`top: -10px` or so).

In general, when faced with an issue such as this - use the inspectors in the browsers. They are really excellent tools and will highlight elements and help you spot overlaps or things that aren't working. Best of luck!

Comment: @Ruddy Thanks for fixing the formatting! I never knew what char converted text to "html". You wouldn't happen to have a link for any other formatting syntax would you?

Comment: Thanks Ruddy! It seems what I'm doing is faux pas, so I'll stop being stubborn and put it in the a's.  Maybe totally take out the divs and only use "display:block" a's?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
a.block {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

and add `display: block;` to both `div.begin` and `div.late`.

Also, you don't have to use `div` in front of every class in your css-file. The `.` (for classes) and `#` (for ids) are enough. But that's something you didn't ask about ;)

Comment: Thanks, Rvervuurt.  I believe, those divs are already blocks?  Thanks for taking the time.  I'll optimize my class naming =].

Comment: No, your divs weren't blocks yet. The a tags you put within your divs were blocks :)

Comment: aren't divs normally blocks?

Comment: The thing is: If you have an a-tag within a div, and you want the whole div to become clickable without wrapping it with a-tags, you have to use display:block on the divs.